# How do I code applications on a Mac so that they use the native UI elements?

Tags: macos

I'm starting to program. Already did some things with Java: a calculator, one document management system powered with a database and some other home projects. But I don't like the visual look. I love however how mi Mac's Apps look. And I want to create Apps for mac. Already buy one but when I open netbeans to program it looks like the Apps doesn't feel like mac.

Is there any specific java code to make the controls looks like how the other mac apps look? My dad mention something about Object C but I don't understand. Can someone please explain me.

Comment: Since no one has posted this link yet, [take a look at the Mac Dev Center on Apple’s website](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action)! There are some good articles on there (click around the "getting started" section), but you might also want to buy a book about Cocoa or Mac programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. AFAIK You'll never get the *look and feel* of Aqua (Mac's UI Kit) by using Java. Why? Because to make Java platform independent some things needs to get ripped off. And native controls are one of them.
2. I think you're taking about *Objective C* which is the native development language for building Mac Apps. I'll recommend you the book "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" is pretty useful.

P.S. I'll encourage you to start with iOS (iPhone and iPad apps). Why? Well, I think is easier to begin with. Things like fixed resolution and so on make your development efforts small while beginning with. (Just my 2 cents)

Comment: Thank you Randolf. Just one more thing. Are iOS apps created with Objective too?

Comment: @Angela V - everything on the iPhone/iPad/iOS are created with Objective-C

Comment: Thank you @afuzzyllama now I get also what @ means :)

Comment: Cocoa-Java, while deprecated, disproves statement #1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to code in Objective-C, you'll first need to trek over to the App Store and download Xcode.  This will install C/C++/Objective-C compilers on your Mac and then you can start getting your hands dirty.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can just google/read/learn and build your own frameworks from the ground up or look at something like Cocoa to get started as well.

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html

> Cocoa Frameworks
>   The Cocoa frameworks consist of libraries, APIs, and runtimes that form the development layer for all of Mac OS X. By developing with Cocoa, you will be creating applications the same way Mac OS X itself is created. Your application will automatically inherit the great behaviors and appearances of Mac OS X, with full access to the underlying power of the UNIX operating system. Using Cocoa with the Xcode IDE is simply the best way to create native Mac applications.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you afuzzyllama, one question, when you say cocoa you mean real cocoa or is another programming language? (sorry but I get used to my dad code-names). Excuse me if its an dumb question

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of Objective C.  You can also do applications for Mac using C/C++ but as of late the "popular" language for Mac development is Objective-C. There are tons of tutorials and plenty of documentation to walk you through writing apps for both Mac and iOS.

Comment: Thanks Jesus for the fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

Apple has deprecated a lot of the Java support in OS X. It's possible to have a Java application integrated, but there are some annoying bits missing. See [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153592/dropping-files-on-application-icon-in-dock/) demonstrating some issues with Java applications in the Dock. You would be better off using Objective-C instead, since Apple has lots of documentation and tutorials available.

Comment: vmorell do you think that is better to drop off my interested with Java? It has taken me some months to start with it and not in windows nor in mac it looks good.

Comment: If you want to development for Mac Platform, that should keep mainly in Cocoa Framework as Fast-Robust-Native, but If you consider to development for cross-platform application or used many Opensource library inside your app. Java is Best Choice